# Why is Xcode 12.2 as large as macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, xcode

Just as the title says...

- Xcode 12.2 is a 11.4 GB
- MacOS Big Sur is a 12.18 GB

Xcode is just an application while Big Sur is a complete Operating System. How come a macOS application is as large as the OS itself?

Is Xcode bringing in components that are not part of the standard OS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xcode 12.2 unpacked is 16.8 GB, 13.2 GB of which are platform operating systems.

- iPhoneOS.platform is 5.9 GB
- AppleTVOS.platform is 3.6 GB
- WatchOS.platform is 3.3 GB

In comparison, MacOSX.platform is only ~300 MB since most of the platform is already available in a normal installation of macOS. Xcode doesn't just build apps for macOS — it also builds apps for other operating systems and runs a simulator of each OS.

Answer (score 1):

`Xcode` is considerably more than just one application. Nowadays, it essentially bundles all developer tools, and all header files — practically everything that is only relevant to developers and not to end users.

You might find it instructive to open a terminal window and run

`ls -lR /Applications/Xcode.app`

or

`du -m /Applications/Xcode.app`